# how to hide keyboard on button click in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need to hide the keyboard on a click button in windows phone 8.1 using c# and i trying this: SignIn.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard)
but the keyboard still open

Comment: The on-screen keyboard normally disappears when focus is passed to a control that cannot take textual input, so perhaps you could provide a little more information on your issue, or an example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: private void SignIn_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     SignIn.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard) ;        
     doLogin();
 }

Comment: where SignIn is the name of a button

Answer (score 1):

You can try use [InputPane class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.aspx).

Sample:

```
private void HideKeyboard()
{
    var current = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
    current.TryHide();
}
```